# GWT Canvas2D draw Image

Tags: gwt, canvas

```
/**
 * This is the entry point method.
 */
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
    final Context2d context2d = canvas.getContext2d();

    RootPanel.get("canvas").add(canvas);
    Image img = new Image("face.png");
    final ImageElement face = ImageElement.as(img.getElement());
    img.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
            context2d.drawImage(face, 0, 0);
        }
    });
    //RootPanel.get("canvas").add(img);
}
```

This is my code. I want to draw the image onto the canvas. 
This works if the last line:

RootPanel.get("canvas").add(img);

is NOT commented out.

But with the line commented it seems that the image wont be loaded or so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you placed the image within the WEB-INF folder? That's where GWT loads the images from. Normally it's recommend to create an "images" folder so you can load it with "images/face.png".

Answer (score 4):

The Image widget has to be added to the page to trigger image load. Just make it invisible:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {    
    Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
    final Context2d context2d = canvas.getContext2d();

    RootPanel.get().add(canvas);
    Image img = new Image("face.png");
    final ImageElement face = ImageElement.as(img.getElement());
    img.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
            context2d.drawImage(face, 0, 0);
        }
    });

    img.setVisible(false);
    RootPanel.get().add(img);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, except I had to put the img.setVisible(false); inside the onLoad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image loader, such as: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ImageLoader.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid needing to add the image to the page to load (which can cause the image to flash up on the page), you can use a native JavaScript load.

```java
package com.mypackage;

public interface Loaded<T> {
    public void data(T data);
}
```

```java
public static native void loadImageNative(String imgBase64, Loaded<ImageElement> loaded) /*-{
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        loaded.@com.mypackage.Loaded::data(*)(image);
    };
    image.src = imgBase64;
}-*/;

public void onModuleLoad() {    
    Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
    Context2d context2d = canvas.getContext2d();
    String base64Img = MyResouces.myImage().getSafeUri().asString();

    RootPanel.get().add(canvas);

    loadImageNative(base64Img, imageLoaded -> {
        context2d.drawImage(imageLoaded, 0, 0);
    });
}
```